# Progressive JPEG in an UIImageView iOS 9 and above Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview, progressive-download

Downloading an image from the url and show as progressive JPEG (and PNG) image in iPhone.

I came across iOS Library for download and decode progressive JPEGs **[Concorde](https://github.com/contentful-labs/Concorde)**, which is supporting from iOS 8.0 and above.

Anyone can help me out for this Progressive JPEG for iOS 9 and above supported code or library?

Comment: It will support for ios 9

Comment: @JitendraModi I tried with minimum iOS support 9, then it is showing error and in that library they used `NSURLConnection`. In iOS 9 **NSURLConnection deprecated**.

Comment: it means you have to replace NSURLConnection in ios 9 with its nondeprecated version'

Comment: yes, then progressive JPEG functionality wont work I hope so. Because, it is working based on `connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:`.

Comment: You can do one thing, give your application support of ios 8 then its successfully working in all OS

Comment: @JitendraModi No, I can't do that. I want to start support from iOS 9. Sorry about this.

Comment: I will try to convert library Please wait. If I get success then I will contact you'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145759/discussion-between-antony-raphel-and-jitendra-modi).